# Redshift: Table columns can be found in information_schema.columns but not in pg_catalog.pg_table_def

Tags: table, redshift

I create a table in Redshift. When I tried to search for the table definition, I get back results from `information_schema.columns` by running the following query:

```
select * from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'table' and table_schema='schema'
```

However, when I run a query against `pg_catalog.pg_table_def`, I don't get back any result.

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_table_def 
where tablename = 'table' and  schemaname = 'schema'
```

Could anyone help me understand why this is happening? The table is created and owned by the account I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `show search_path;` to make sure you are on the current path where the table was created.
As stated on the original AWS redshift [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html).

> PG_TABLE_DEF only returns information about tables that are visible to the user.

to get what you want you should run

`set search_path to '$user', '<#your_schema#>';
select * from pg_catalog.pg_table_def where tablename = '<#your_table#>';`

Hope that helps.